# How grab starting scroll position with differences in all the browsers on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I need to call a function based on whether the scroll position is at 0 vs anywhere else. The issue is that I can't use `jQuery(document).ready(...)` in all the browsers, nor the `scroll` event listener. The reasons are:

1. If the page is scrolled beyond 0 *(meaning they scrolled the page and then reloaded it, so it starts at the "remembered" scroll position)*, then jQuery's `ready` function happens too soon on all non-chrome browsers (they report 0 in there), and the scroll event is kicked off **after** the `ready` function

   a. IE (non-edge): `ready` has `scrollTop` 0, then it throws a scroll event and reports the new value (e.g. 243)

   b. IE Edge: `ready` has `scrollTop` 0, then it throws a scroll event and reports the new value (e.g. 243)

   c. Chrome actually fires a scroll event *before* `ready` with the new value, then fires `ready`. Both of them report the new value (e.g. 243)

   d. Safari actually fires a scroll event *before* `ready` with the new value, then fires `ready`. Both of them report the new value (e.g. 243)

   e. Firefox `ready` has `scrollTop` 0, then it throws a scroll event and reports the new value (e.g. 243)
2. If the page starts at 0, then the scroll event is ***never*** thrown (on any browser)!

The issue is that when it's 0, I need to do some animations and prevent scrolling (until some user-interaction is done). If the scroll event is fired after that, I have no way to know the page should be there instead of the user trying to scroll to there.

And I can't just wait for the scroll event, because if it *is* at 0, it will never be fired.

And using `setTimeout` could result in an error, and too long of a delay.

You can see the issue here: http://test-scroll-issue.bitballoon.com/

A page that shows the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Test</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a

<script>
window.getScrollTopValue = function()
{
    return ( window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0 );
};

jQuery( document ).ready(
    function() { console.log( "Ready: " + getScrollTopValue() ); }
);

document.addEventListener(
    "scroll",
    function (event)
    {
        console.log( "Scroll: " + getScrollTopValue() );
    }
);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I get the scroll position on load regardless of if it's at 0 or some other position?

Comment: First instinct: don't mess with the browser's behavior of moving back to the user's old scroll position. Second comment: I'm getting around 5 miliseconds between the `ready` and the `scroll` event. Would be an option to wait 20ms after document ready for a scroll event and assume it's at 0 if nothing happens?

Comment: @user3297291 I understand the instinct but it's needed here (to show a full page user-interaction piece). The issue is that the delay between the two events is not guaranteed to be that amount. If something takes a longer time to load, it could be much higher.

Comment: Agreed. Only work-around I can think of is to store scroll position in `localStorage` and use that to try and predict what the browser will do...

Comment: maybe you can play with location hash property:on scroll event somethig like:`document.location.hash = $(window).scrollTop();` then on (re)load you're able to know if document.location.hash==='' or '0' or whatever

Comment: **sidenote:** if you put `document.ready` inside the `<body>`, it kinda defeats the purpose... By the time `<body>` has been loaded and the script inside it is executed, the document's DOM is obviously ready, so `document.ready` is useless now (and so is `window.load` btw). In the *console* you can even see that `document.ready` actually fires **_after_** `window.load` now. *This should be the other way around!*  **Put your `<script>` inside the `<head>` for it to work properly (not just this time, always).**